# regex.Match runs slow

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program extracting some information from a lot of large html pages. I found that the last line (`myRegex.Match(detailPage)`) takes most of the execution time. Is the regex pattern optimized?

```
const string strRegex = @"prepend-top.*?<h1[^>]*?>(?<name>.+?)\s*<a.*?
    Create\ Date.*?<label>(?<create>.*?)</label>.*?
    <a.*?id\s*=\s*""period_report"".*?href\s*=\s*""(?<url>.*?)""";
const RegexOptions myRegexOptions =
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
var m = myRegex.Match(detailPage);
```

The HTML code looks like (The html file size is about 30K, however, most of the the html is javascript code):

```html
<div class="span-24 prepend-top">
<h1>XXX XXX XXXX 
    <a href="https://....">Back to Search Results</a></h1>
</div>

<div class="span-18">
<div class="top-content">

<script type="text/javascript">
 .....
</script>

    <div class="detailHeaderContainer">
        <div class="leftBlock">

            <div class="left staticlabel leftStaticlabelWidth inlineColumn">
                <label>
                    Product Type:
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="left leftDynamiclabelWidth dynamiclabel">
                <label>Type 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="left staticlabel leftStaticlabelWidth inlineColumn">
                <label>
                    Create Date:
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="left leftDynamiclabelWidth dynamiclabel">
                <label></label>
            </div>
```

Comment: welcome to the world of regex.  how large is the string that the regex is checking?

Comment: @Brian The size of the html file is about 30KB.

Comment: You're using to many `.`, it's an eager operator. Try changing it to something more specific, maybe a char sequence. Also, surround whichever group that you don't want to capture with `(?:your_pattern)`

Comment: Agreed.  this comple of a regex on a 30 kb file is going to be slow. is regex the only option or could you do it with jquery or use XPath as an alternative?

Comment: Consider that learning experience and switch to more suitable tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: A better question would be "why am I using a regular expression to parse HTML?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create static RegEx class can save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a quick look at the [regex best practices guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx) and [This blog entry on the BCL team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/08/03/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-ii-taking-charge-of-backtracking.aspx), they go into the behaviors of Regex and can provide guidance as to why regexs can be slow